# build android framework.jar only

Tags: android

Having add some debug information to `androd.opengl.GLSurfaceView` , I want to rebuild  the `framework.jar` `only` in the android source tree. I did a `mm` in $ANDROID_ROOT but that would build the apps as well and some apps failed to compile but I did not bother with the apps.How could I build the `framework.jar` only?

Furthermore, in the `build/core/main.mk`,`incrementaljavac` was said to be able to speed up the compilation. How that flag could be used here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.

`mm` command in the `framework/base` will do the job , it compile both framework.jar and framework-ext.jar though.